Error on generating apk release on flutter windows "resource style/Theme.Material not found"
keep on getting this same error while generation my apk please help out with any solution tried evrythig have already tried

Flutter clean & pud get & flutter clean pub get
gradle clean and build
change gradle properties to 'org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m'

the error code\ Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseResources'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnable
Android resource linking failed
error: resource style/Theme.MaterialComponents (aka com.mettcab.user:style/Theme.MaterialComponents) not found.
error: resource style/Theme.MaterialComponents (aka com.mettcab.user:style/Theme.MaterialComponents) not found.
error: failed linking references.

/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml


    
    
        
        @drawable/launch_background
    
    
    
        ?android:colorBackground
    

/android/app/src/main/res/values-night/styles.xml


    
    
    
        
        @drawable/launch_background
    
    
    
        ?android:colorBackground
    

gradle project v- 8.5 all
flutter 3.24.5
kotlin 1.9.10
jdk 17.13..
